# What are the proper ways to centralize the logs of spring boot microservices deployed in Kubernetes?

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, logging, microservices

I would like to have a way to centralize the logs of multiple applications running in a Kubernetes cluster.

The cherry on top would be if there could be a way to query them so I can display them on a UI.

Any ideas / suggestions?

Comment: fluentd + elasticsearch + kibana is the common open source logging stack, but there are tons of hosted logging options as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by the `Jordanm` you can use the flientd + ES and Kibana (Display log).

i would also suggest checking the same stack Graylog, Elasticsearch and MongoDb.

You are on Kubernetes so this way it would be easy to integrate the Graylog also and it's open-source tool. You can use the official helm chart and deploy it for storing the central logs.

Helm chart to deploy the Graylog : https://charts.kong-z.com/

Graylog official site : https://www.graylog.org/

i would also suggesting checking out the Gelf UDP option with Graylog so your application have to send logs over UDP protocol so under immense traffic also your application can survive and write log without waiting **ack**.